# Chocolat.JS - Transform title to Download Button - Moving span class content into href

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm using [chocolat.js](https://github.com/nicolas-t/Chocolat/blob/master/readme.md) in a simple gallery website. I would love to build a download button out of the title tag. While creating the grid etc. I'm writing the image path with php into the title tag. 
 Looking threw the javascript code I think I found the part responsible for displaying the title.
*this.elems.description = $('', {
                'class' : 'chocolat-description'
            }).appendTo(this.elems.bottom);*

Changing the span to an anchor tag and adding a href works, but I'm just not good enough in javascript to get the content of the span tag into the href… I tried finding similar threads but wasn't able to find something that helps.
Would be really awesome to get some help finishing this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this done by adding a new attribute. You can look at the code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zid7t1dwjh0pinm/jquery.chocolat.js?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>QIndex</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var title = $("#replaceDomElems").html();
            $("#outerDiv").html("<a href='#' >" + title + "</a>");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <span id="replaceDomElems">Title..</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```